# How can I stack opengl shapes into std::vector

Tags: c++, opengl, stl

How can I stack up these two opengl shapes into a container class? 
can someone please show me
I wont mind a template.

```
void myTriangle()
 {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glLoadIdentity();                                   
glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);                     
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                      
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                      
    glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);                      
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                      
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  
glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers ( );
  }

void myQuad()
 {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();
glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);                      
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                              
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                    
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                    
      glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                    
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                    
    glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers ( );
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not really sure of what you want to do, but you can do:

```
typedef void (*ShapeFct_t)();
typedef std::vector<ShapeFct_t> ShapeArray_t;

ShapeArray_t shapes;
shapes.push_back(myTriangle);
shapes.push_back(myQuad);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `Shape` base class, and have `Quad` and `Triangle` inherit from that class with an overloaded `draw` function. Here's a *simplified*, *incomplete* **example**:

```
/* Define these; use tuples, your own class, 3rd party, whatever */
class Position;
class Color;

/* Shape class is abstract base class */
class Shape {
public:
    Shape(const Position &pos) : position(pos) {}
    virtual void draw() = 0;
protected:
    Position position;
};

/* Triangle and Quad classes are Shapes */
class Triangle : public Shape {
public:
    Triangle(const Position &pos,
             const Position &p1, const Color &c1, 
             const Position &p2, const Color &c2, 
             const Position &p3, const Color &c3)
        : Shape(pos),
          pos1(p1), col1(c1),
          pos2(p2), col2(c2),
          pos3(p3), col3(c3)
    {}

    virtual void draw() {
        glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                      
        glColor3f(col1.r, col1.g, col1.b);                      
        glVertex3f(pos1.x, pos1.y, pos1.z);              
        glColor3f(col2.r, col2.g, col2.b);                      
        glVertex3f(pos2.x, pos2.y, pos2.z);             
        glColor3f(col3.r, col3.g, col3.b);                      
        glVertex3f(pos3.x, pos3.y, pos3.z);                    
        glEnd();
    }
private:
    Position pos1, pos2, pos3;
    Color col1, col2, col3;
};

class Quad : public Shape {
    /* Your implementation here */
};

void draw_all_shapes() {

    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
    shapes.push_back(new Triangle(Position(-1.5f, 0f, -6f),
        Position(0f, 1f, 0f), Color(1f, 0f, 0f),
        Position(-1f, -1f, 0f), Color(0f, 1f, 0f),
        Position(0f, 0f, 1f),  Color(0f, 0f, 1f)));

    shapes.push_back(new Quad(/* Arguments */));

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();  
    for(auto it = shapes.begin(); it != shapes.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->draw();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

**Note:** As I said, the example is incomplete. It's also untested and a little bit messy (memory leaks and such) but those problems are out of the scope of this question. The main point I am trying to demonstrate here is that you can convert your functions to classes, which can leverage inheritance and polymorphism to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you care to edit what the shape looks like after you create it but you could put it in a display list, then store each display list in whatever container you like:

```
GLuint triangleList = glGenLists(1);
glNewList(triangleList, GL_COMPILE);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glLoadIdentity();                                   
glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);                     
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                      
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                      
    glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);                      
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                      
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  
glEnd();
glEndList();

GLuint quadList = glGenList(1);
glNewList(quadList, GL_COMPILE);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();
glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);                      
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                              
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                    
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                    
      glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                    
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                    
    glEnd();
glEndList();
```

At this point you can store the quadList and triangleList in whatever container you like.  You can tell OpenGL to display them by using the `glCallList()` function.  To delete the list call `glDeleteList()`.